# How to setNull on the MYSQL Database (Date Datatype)

Tags: java, mysql, date, prepared-statement

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(Module.url, Module.username, Module.password);
String sql = "Update resume set Start = ? where ID = '" + ID.getText() + "'";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setNull(1, 0);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

ps is PreparedStatement, the datatype of the field is DATE.
how can i set it to Null not to "0000-00-00".

Comment: Can you provide your ddl? The column `start`must be nullable.

Comment: dis yo set the column to allow null **true**

Comment: CREATE TABLE `resume` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

This is my sql code

Comment: is that are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this..
    `ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.Date);` 
where `java.sql.Types.Date` is SQL Datatype

Comment: i try your codes but its returning to "0000-00-00".
i want to is (Null).

Comment: Add the parameter `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to the connection url **which will automatically convert the “zero” date to NULL**. E.g., 
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`